# html2canvas issue on IE but works fine with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html2canvas

I was trying to capture an image of google map using html2canvas plugin. I was able to capture the image in Chrome as well as in Mozilla Firefox. But not able to get in Internet Explorer.

*Image captured using Internet Explorer.* [image: I am getting an image like this]

*Image captured from Chrome and Mozilla*

[image]

I am using the following html2canvas code:

```
html2canvas($('#map'), {
    useCORS: true,
    logging:true,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    uploadImage(dataUrl,canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue before so, i found solution in official github.

Ill share my example to you:

```js
html2canvas($("#your_ID_obj"),
{   
    logging: false,
    useCORS: true, //
    onrendered: function(canvas)
    {
        // Restore if is chrome
        if(window.chrome) {// Fix for Chrome
            $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({
                left:0,
                top:0,
                "transform":transform
            });
        }

        // Function with your code to do whatever you need
    }
});
```